# Add text to TextBlock Text property when it's binded

Tags: c#, wpf, text, binding, textblock

I have a `TextBlock` where its `Text` property is binded with another property that rappresents a value:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Count}" FontWeight="Bold" />
```

So, if (for example) `Count` is `4`, I'll see in my TextBlock the number **4**.

Now, what I have to do if I want to add some text before and after the number 4 (for example I'd like to see that number in square brackets **[4]**)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You sould use stringformat

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Count, StringFormat={}[{0}]}" FontWeight="Bold" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also try with - Based on `MultiBinding`

```
<TextBlock.Text>
    <MultiBinding StringFormat=" {0}{1}{2}">
        <Binding Path="Prefixe"/>
        <Binding Path="Count"/>
        <Binding Path="Suffixe"/> 
    </MultiBinding>
</TextBlock.Text>
```

Nota : Set Suffixe and Prefix